# How to stop a CronJob function, inside the CronJob function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I know the question is kinda confusing haha but let me elaborate:

I am using this package in my Node.js project:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
```

I have a varaiable initialized to be this:

```
var cronClose = false;
```

Now, once the function that I am executing in my CronJob completes a specific requirement, I change `cronClose = true` inside that function and am returning it. In the case of my project, the function I am refering to is `checkClassCapacity`. I am hoping to do something like this:

```
    let job = new CronJob('0/15 * * * * *', function() {
    var cronClose = checkClassCapacity(cookies, browser, classPage);
    if (cronClose) {
        job.stop();
        console.log('CronJob has been stopped.')
    }
    }, null, true, null, null, true);
```

But this is apparently wrong as I am getting this error:

```
(node:49818) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'job' before 
initialization
at CronJob.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/folder/proj/app.js:78:13)
```

Which makes total sense. But I don't know how else to close the CronJob. Any advise or tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
let job = new CronJob('0/15 * * * * *', function() {
    var cronClose = checkClassCapacity(cookies, browser, classPage);
    if (cronClose) {
        return
        console.log('CronJob has been stopped.')
    }
    }, null, true, null, null, true);
```

try to return the function may it help.